# Passing objects to different libraries in Java

Tags: java, object, libraries, pass-by-value

This is a question regarding best practices to pass an Object into a different Library or Project.

Lets say we have a class called Student and Grades.

```
 import Grades; 

 public class Student (){
      String StudentName;
      String StudentID;
      int age;
      int gradeForMath;
      int gradeForScience;
      Grades otherGrades; 
 }
```

Now in our main class I want to pass the Grades class and some Integers into a library to calculate the likelihood of the student passing the next year.

```
 public static void main (){
      MyExternalLibraryCalculatingPassRate passRate = new MyExternalLibraryCalculatingPassRate(Grades otherGrades, int math, int science); 
 }
```

However, My problem is that the Library has no visibility to Grades nor has a class called Grades. My question really is, what is the best way of doing this? I have the two ideas below but I am not sure if there is a better or worse way -

1. Pass the underlying data structure of Grades. For instance if we can boil down grades to a hashmap or an arraylist or what ever then pass that?
2. Create a Grades class in the library and import that into your project and use the Grades class from the library in your project without declaring a Grades class in your project?

I am not convinced that both these approaches are good - however what is best practice? Or commonly done?

Comment: what is the method signature of the library? is it accepting `Grades` in the signature.

Comment: @SajanChandran You're missing the point, the library is his/hers. Making API's pass raw data is a good idea btw. If all the library needs is a hashmap of stuff then #1 is a good idea.

Comment: The separation of API seems a little unusual as both your code as well as the library operates on the same domain. However, since you wish to keep the library totally separate, better would be option 1 if you could unambiguously define the keys. The best would be to expose an interface from the library and implement (as suggested below)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your library and main project operate on the same domain, so I think the best idea is just to share common data model. If `MyExternalLibraryCalculatingPassRate` calculates probability if `Student` will pass, maybe it will be better make the method to consume `Student` object, not the `Grades` and two primitives. Generally, mixing Objects and primitives to represent same conception is a bad idea.

-- update

I see other problems with this code, Student class has only fields. So if other classes want to get grades, they should know internal representation of grades (one `Grades` field and two `ints`) and that is generally  bad thing.

Comment: The student class is just an example but no in the real class there are some methods. Also I want to keep the library separate for reasons that the library then can be used for other things as well?

Comment: Reusable libraries are good things, but in this case `MyExternalLibraryCalculatingPassRate ` suggest that it calculates some kind probability from School/Class domain. How would you to reuse it in other domains? Maybe it is better to create library responsible for calculating probability, that is rather general thing and it is not limited to the specific domain and could be used by some `CalculatingPassRate` class. Then creating library limited only to the calculating probability of pass rate wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. The student class is just an example but in the real class there are some methods. As well as Grades and the math and science mark which are passed in as separate variables for simplicity of explanation here but in the real case they are different values conceptually.

Comment: Libraries should be flexible. In a sense, it should be possible and it should make sense to use them in different projects/contexts/domains. For example, the library which operates on graphs knows what is Edge, Node and so on, it knows how to calculate shortest path between nodes. And this library could be used in other application which is used to plan cargo, public transport and so one but first of all developer have to provide some translation from the transport/cargo domain to the vertex domain and that translation should be done in the application.

Comment: Yup, that sounds reasonable I think. Its probably the approach I will take.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an interface in your external library that specifies how data must be organized but without providing an implementation.
ex:

```
public class StudentPassRateData {
      int getGradeForMath();
      int getGradeForScience();
}
```

Then, in the main project, you can define a class that implements this interface:

```
public class Student implements StudentPassRateData {
      private String StudentName;
      private String StudentID;
      private int age;
      private int gradeForMath;
      private int gradeForScience;
      private Grades otherGrades; 

      int getGradeForMath() {return gradeForMath;}
      int getGradeForScience() {return gradeForScience;}
 }
```